# Error in React App links not properly work

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm a beginner in MERN stack. I want to use Links in React App it will work fine without dashboard stats and chart. But when I add the component of dashboard stats and chart then it will not work.

React Code:

App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router ,Link} from "react-router-dom";

<Route path='/t_sale'    component={t_sales}/>
<Route path='/t_customer' component={t_customers}/>
<Route path='/t_item'     component={t_items}/>
<Route path='/t_expense'  component={t_expenses}/>
```

Dashboard.js:

```
<h4><Link to='/t_sale'>Total Sales</Link></h4>
<h4><Link to='/t_customer'>Total Customer</Link></h4>
<h4><Link to='/t_item'>Total Items</Link></h4>
<h4><Link to='/t_expense'>Total Expense</Link></h4>
```

[Dashboard stats error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Vwp.png)

Comment: Can you show us the code for that side-bar?

Comment: what kind of error is thrown in the console? and Also the Route has `BrowserRouter ` has to be parent of `Route` components

Comment: Thanks, @ChristopherNgo problem is solved when I add z-index:-1 then it will create a problem. Now I remove this from the side menu.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
<Link to='/t_sale'><h4>Total Sales</h4></Link>
<Link to='/t_customer><h4>Total Customer</h4></Link>
<Link to='/t_item'><h4>Total Items</h4></Link>
<Link to='/t_expense'><h4>Total Expense</h4></Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure `BrowserRouter` is the parent.

2) Try using NavLink

3) Try specifying 'exact'

```
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

<BrowserRouter>
       //exact
       <Route path='' exact component={}/>
       <Route path='' exact component={}/>
</BrowserRouter>


<NavLink to={} exact />
```